# MS Access ComboBox with own values

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

In my MS Access application I have table and form Customers which contains Numeric field `Status` (`1`- means `Active`, `2` - `Inactive`, `3` - `N/A`)

On the form I need to have combobox with values `Active`, `Inactive` and `NA`, and when user selects any value, `1`,`2` or `3` value should save into `Status` field.

When I try to set up `[Row Source Type]` as `[Value List]` and `[Row Source]` as `["Active";1;"Inactive";2;"NA";3]`, `[Bound Column] =2`, the combobox shows me needless column with values `1`,`2`,`3`

When I set up `[Bound Column] = 1`, it tries to store in table `["Active", "Inactive", "NA"]` instead of `1`,`2`,`3`

Who knows how it's possible to implement, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set up ColumnCount =2 to tell access you have two columns in your string and ColumnsWidth=";0" to tel him to hide second?

Comment: That works! Please write this as answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [Value List] as [Row Source Type] you have to set ColumnCount to right value manually.

```
ColumnCount = 2
```

Also hide ID column

```
ColumnsWidth=";0"
```